# Downloading data after fix interval in android

Tags: android

i want to Update my database with data that is downloaded from the server. i want to download the data from the server after a fix time interval and update the database without keeping my activities unresponsive .

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                downloadFromServerAndUpdateDatabase();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
            h.postDelayed(this,10000);
        }
    };
```

But i want to do this when my application is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for this kind of functionality. You can easily find various [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) and blogs about it.

Comment: Oh I can use service to download in background. Thanks